# How to get data some table data in a url using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get some data in a website but my code is not really working. I am new to python and I am just trying to get some code working. Any idea or help to make this work is very welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0",}

url = "https://mine.com/blockexplorer/account/GDOI7OSBDM3WPXWFT3RUPGGLV3Y5MKZJKNN4CZMQITUWWQRUF5IXCLZJ"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
t = soup.find("table", class_="table")
trs = t.find("tbody").find_all("tr")

for tr in trs:
    print(list(tr.stripped_strings))
```

Current result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/es***a/Desktop/Pi Scripts/pi-temp1.py", line 14, in <module>
    trs = t.find("tbody").find_all("tr")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Need result:

```
Public Key: GDOI7OSBDM3WPXWFT3RUPGGLV3Y5MKZJKNN4CZMQITUWWQRUF5IXCLZJ
Balance: 26.9231952
```

Comment: As so often happens, you have not actually looked at the HTML that this site delivers.  If you do "View Source" in your browser, you'll see that there are no tables on that page.  There's almost no HTML at all.  The page is all built dynamically, using Javascript.  You will need to use a browser to do your capture, using something like Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an API you can use to get the data:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0',
}

public_key = "GDOI7OSBDM3WPXWFT3RUPGGLV3Y5MKZJKNN4CZMQITUWWQRUF5IXCLZJ"
url = f"https://api.testnet.minepi.com/accounts/{public_key}"

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
balances = response['balances']
for balance in balances:
    print(f"Public Key: {response['account_id']}")
    print(f"Balance: {balance['balance']}")
```

Note: for the key you've provided this is the result

```
Public Key: GDOI7OSBDM3WPXWFT3RUPGGLV3Y5MKZJKNN4CZMQITUWWQRUF5IXCLZJ
Balance: 100.0000000
```

Comment: In the url, there are 2 buttons namely: **Testnet** and **Mainnet** and I am trying to get the Mainnet data

Comment: That's the API used behind the scenes. There's no other endpoint that points to `mainnet`, as data on `minepi` uses `api.testnet.minepi.com`. Double check the public key.